# Upload pipeline on kubeflow

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am currently trying to setup a kubeflow pipeline. My use case requires that the configuration for pipelines shall be provided via a yaml/json structure. Looking into the documentation for submitting pipelines I came across this paragraph:

> Each pipeline is defined as a Python program. Before you can submit a pipeline to the Kubeflow Pipelines service, you must compile the pipeline to an intermediate representation. The intermediate representation takes the form of a YAML file compressed into a .tar.gz file.

Is is possible to upload/submit a pipeline to KubeFlow via json representation or any other representation instead of a zip file(tar.gz) representation? Is there a way to bypass the filesystem persistence of files(zips and tar.gz) and add them into database as a yaml/json representation?

Comment: When you say that the configuration for your pipeline is provided as YAML/JSON, do you mean:

1. The steps and order they are to be executed in are defined in this configuration file?
2. The configuration parameters for each step are passed in to the pipeline in a YAML or JSON file.

Comment: This official example called Simple Notebook Pipeline provides an option by using KFP python SDK. see https://github.com/kubeflow/examples/blob/master/pipelines/simple-notebook-pipeline/Simple%20Notebook%20Pipeline.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

When you compile your python pipeline code then it results in a compressed file containing a `YAML` file. You can take out the YAML file after decompressing it and you can add its contents to your database table.

> Later If you want to upload it to `Kubeflow` then use the following code:

```
 pipeline_file_path = 'pipelines.yaml' # extract it from your database
 pipeline_name = 'Your Pipeline Name'

 client = kfp.Client()
 pipeline = client.pipeline_uploads.upload_pipeline(
                                pipeline_file_path, name=pipeline_name)
```

Comment: using a tar.gz file directly does work too with v2 sdk